# check array values exist in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to check the array values which contains more than 400 values which is existing in the MySQL table where i should get result for all the values which I am passing even if it not exist in the column.

for example:

```
cont table
----------
Column1                  
---------             

9xxxxxxxxx

91xxxxxxxx

92xxxxxxxx
```

my array contains `9xxxxxxxxx` & `91xxxxxxxx`. How can i iterate to get the column exist or not.

I tried with `foreach` and building query

```
$sql = 'SELECT cont WHERE num IN(';

foreach($jsonString as $val){ 

$sql = $sql . "'$val', ";

echo $val;

}

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){  
    echo "exist";
}else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Is there any efficient way other than the above which is faster in time?

Comment: what is this?if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){  
    echo "exist";
}else {
    echo "error";
}

Comment: You will always have a trailing comma and space at the end of the sql statement.  You would be better off imploding the array `implode( ',', $jsonString )`

Comment: @Blinkydamo: yup you r right,

Comment: @devpro you too, have an up vote :)

Comment: did u checked? ..

Answer (score 4):

First of all if `cont` is your table name than where is `FROM` keyword.

If `cont` is column name than where is `TABLE` name?

As per your question, you have 400+ ids, than why are you using loop here? you can simply use `implode()` with comma seperated values, like

```
<?php
$ids = implode(",",$jsonString);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cont WHERE num IN ($ids)"; // assuming cont is table name
?>
```

*In your loop you will get the "," in last iteration at the end this will break your query.*